A horror movie where the boy looks for his mom inside their house
I'm pretty young when I saw this movie...I think it's an american horror film probably during the late 90's or early 2000
There's only few things I remember in the movie and I don't exactly know what's the plot of this movie

There is a blonde boy in his pajamas (I think)
He is looking for his mom inside their house
There is a scene where he went to the bathroom and there is a bathtub with a white curtain covering it...and it seems like someone is inside the tub (because there is a silhouette) and the kid thinks it his mom.
The boy opened the curtain and there something/someone in it but I'm not sure if it is his mom but I guessed not because he ran away scared/shocked.

I hope someone can help me figure out this movie with such a little info I can give...

It's too common in Hollywood horror film to have a bathtub scene and a blonde boy, can you ad any more details. Like how his mom looks, any other scene details etc etc.

I think you're looking for The Shining (1980)

Trailer

Jack Torrance, a writer and recovering alcoholic, takes a job as an
  off-season caretaker at the isolated Overlook Hotel. His young son
  possesses psychic abilities and is able to see things from the past
  and future, such as the ghosts who inhabit the hotel. Some time after
  settling in, the family is trapped in the hotel by a snowstorm, and
  Jack gradually becomes influenced by a supernatural presence, descends
  into madness, and ultimately attempts to murder his wife and son.

The scene you describe is very famous and happens near the middle of the film:
Danny Torrance, a powerful telepath, is lured into room 237 by the hotel and is confronted with the ghost of a woman who was murdered by her young lover in the thirties. This scene fits your description perfectly except for the pajamas, but there are several other scenes in the movie where he is wearing this outfit and I think you may have mixed a few of them together.

IIRC, this is not what happens. It's Jack that encounters the woman in the bath (and he doesn't open the curtain, she does when he's standing far away from her). Danny does enter room 237 before that, but we don't see what happens there, only the aftermath (his clothes are torn). And he wasn't looking for his mom, he was just curious. The movie is also about 20 years off the desired date. So for this to be right, the OP would have to be wrong about everything other than 'blonde boy'. ;)
